# Chrome Consuming a lot of CPU Resources (Possible bg Crypto Miner)

Tags: google-chrome, malware

community,
It's been a month and I feel there is some fishy things going on in my chrome ubuntu 20.04. I think there is a possibility of a miner script running in the background.

With hardly 10 open tabs, a lots of renderer processes are running in the background with cpu consumption up to 200% and overheating
a simple grep search

```
ps -ax | grep renderer
1101201 ?        Sl     0:04 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --extension-process --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=5 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1101228 ?        Sl     0:04 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --extension-process --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=7 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1101241 ?        Sl     2:35 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --extension-process --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=8 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1101254 ?        Sl     3:14 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --extension-process --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=9 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1101261 ?        Sl     0:03 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --extension-process --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=10 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1101282 ?        Sl     5:24 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --extension-process --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=11 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1318369 ?        Sl     0:17 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=144 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1318393 ?        Sl     0:39 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=145 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1367396 ?        Sl     4:59 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --extension-process --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=161 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1469711 ?        Sl     0:55 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --extension-process --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=204 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1470762 ?        Sl    26:13 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --extension-process --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=205 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1691144 ?        Sl     0:13 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=321 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1697661 ?        Sl     0:15 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=328 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1697676 ?        Sl     0:08 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=329 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1697713 ?        Sl     0:29 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=331 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1697732 ?        Sl     0:06 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=332 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1697758 ?        Sl     0:05 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=333 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1855794 ?        Sl    16:16 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=379 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1880789 ?        Sl     0:15 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=427 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1906802 ?        Sl     0:57 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --extension-process --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=452 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1907121 ?        Sl     1:42 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --extension-process --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=455 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1907144 ?        Sl    19:35 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --extension-process --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=456 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1908671 ?        Sl     4:25 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --extension-process --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=480 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1909023 ?        Sl     0:11 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=488 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1912286 ?        Sl     0:12 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=577 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1912325 ?        Sl     0:36 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=579 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1912825 ?        Sl     2:30 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=596 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1913707 ?        Sl    27:58 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --extension-process --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=621 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1914569 ?        Sl     0:18 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=630 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1916824 ?        Sl     1:17 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=645 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1924686 ?        Sl     0:12 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=759 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1924707 ?        Sl     0:11 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=760 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1926185 ?        Sl     3:25 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --disable-databases --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=779 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1926459 ?        Sl    67:32 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=786 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1926901 ?        Sl     0:09 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=801 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1926957 ?        Sl     0:54 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --extension-process --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=805 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1927066 ?        Sl     0:30 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --extension-process --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=811 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1927139 ?        Sl     0:02 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --disable-databases --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --extension-process --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=813 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1936836 ?        Sl     0:06 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --disable-databases --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=855 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1937281 ?        Sl     0:01 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --disable-databases --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=856 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1937324 ?        Sl     0:32 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --disable-databases --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=857 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1937338 ?        Sl     0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --disable-databases --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=858 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1937351 ?        Sl     0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --disable-databases --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=859 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1937385 ?        Sl     0:01 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --disable-databases --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=861 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1937414 ?        Sl     0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --disable-databases --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=863 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1937427 ?        Sl     0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --disable-databases --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=864 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1937431 ?        Sl     0:01 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --disable-databases --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=865 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1937468 ?        Sl     0:01 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --disable-databases --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=867 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1937489 ?        Sl     0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --disable-databases --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=869 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1937502 ?        Sl     0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --disable-databases --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=870 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1937523 ?        Sl     0:01 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --disable-databases --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=871 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1937538 ?        Sl     0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --disable-databases --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=872 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1937558 ?        Sl     0:05 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --disable-databases --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=873 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1938009 ?        Sl     4:28 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --disable-databases --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=886 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1938139 ?        Sl     0:01 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --disable-databases --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=893 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1938296 ?        Sl     0:07 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --disable-databases --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=897 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1939260 ?        Sl     0:09 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=912 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1939892 ?        Sl     0:12 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=931 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1939917 ?        Sl     0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=13588190066567582440,11785890265405621164,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=c8dfd195-ec83-49df-9a6e-a0009ef96a7a, --allow-insecure-localhost --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=932 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
1940371 pts/3    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox renderer
```

I don't think it's normal behaviour. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you could try:

- Reduce Chrome Memory and CPU Usage
- Update Chrome
- Work with fewer tabs
- Remove unnecessary apps and extensions
- Monitor using task manager
- Stop background apps
- Enable hardware acceleration
- Reset Chrome